# Click on a marker to redirect user to a blog post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-geo-mashup

I'm using the following Wordpress and plugins combo.

- Wordpress 2.9.2
- Geo Mashup 1.3.3
- Geo Mashup Custom 1.0

What I want to achieve is when the user clicks on a marker it gets redirected to the blog post associated to it.

I added the following code in my custom.js.

```
GeoMashup.addAction('loadedMap', function( properties, marker ) {
    GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        parent.location.href = properties.home_url + "?p=" + properties.open_object_id ;
    });
});
```

With that code the map loads and redirects to the latest marker created on the map. I'm pretty sure I'm close to the final solution.

I guess i'm using the wrong action call. But I haven't been able to find what i'm looking for.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution for Geo Mashup 1.3.3 makes some assumptions that might possibly change in the future, but are necessary for now:

```
GeoMashup.addAction( 'selectedMarker', function( properties, marker ) { 
  var loc = GeoMashup.locations[ marker.getPoint() ]; 
  if ( loc && loc.objects.length > 0 ) { 
    parent.location.href = properties.home_url + '?p=' + loc.objects[0].object_id; 
  } 
} );
```

Comment: Works pretty nicely. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I hope someone is still reading this to answer...

I want to implement this same change, but I can't find where to add/change that coding you have written.

Unless a newer fix has been developed since you last answered here.

Thanks so much

Comment: The location of the custom.js file is elaborated here: http://code.google.com/p/wordpress-geo-mashup/wiki/Documentation#Custom_JavaScript